# What type of name should an androgynous be given?

Tags: names, women, men-male, androgynous

An androgynous that has both signs of a male and female, should they be given a female name, a male name, or a "neutral" name (like "simcha" or "yona".) Is there any makor for this?

(I realize this might not be a practical question since there is already a discussion about what to do if someone is born a androgynous and have a medical procedure to change the child one way or another.) However from a standpoint that that wouldn't have been done and that the person would live as they are.)

Comment: As an aside. There is no thing really as a 'Jewish' name or a male or female one. Anyone can be called anything. In a get I am not sure what one does with letters like w ch or g from general which have no Hebrew equivalent. This can also be asked about towns and rivers in the get.

Comment: Chaim Sarah, perhaps?

Comment: [Sue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_Named_Sue), perhaps?

Comment: I would have named the child 'minchas chinuch'

Comment: @Matt I don't get the joke

Comment: @Yehoshua a poor attempt on my part, really. The Minchas Chinuch (by R. Yosef Babad) isn't meant to be a book about the halakhos of an androgynous, but he ends up discussing every single mitzva as it would to an androgynous, tumtum, and half-free half-slave male

Answer (score 6):

An androgynous is mostly treated [visibly] like a male in Halacha, despite the "dual/uncertain" Halachic status.

- Mila: An androgynous get a Brit Mila ([Rambam Mila Ch. 1:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2601.htm)). Though without a Bracha. ([ibid 3:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2603.htm))
- Yichud: An androgynous may not be secluded with women, but is allowed to be secluded with men. ([Rambam Isurei Bi'ah Ch. 22:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5122.htm))
- Marital relations: Homosexual relationships are forbidden with an androgynous, regular intercourse is allowed. ([ibid 1:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5101.htm))
- Time-bound Mitzvot - like Tzitizit: An androgynous  is obligated to do them, like males, but without a Bracha (as per the Rambam who doesn't let women make a Bracha on time-bound Mitzvot for which they are exempt). ([Rambam Tzitzis 3:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2403.htm) )
- Dress: An androgynous must wear men's clothing, not women's clothing. (Classic: [Mishna, Bicurim Ch. 4:2](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_00963.html#HtmpReportNum0035_L2). Actual [Tosefta Bicurim 2:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/f/f1b.htm))
- Haircut and shaving: Shaving Payot and shaving beard with a blade is forbidden for an androgynous. (ibid).

In other words, an androgynous who follows halacha will look like a male - and it makes sense (culture-wise) to give an androgynous a male's name, or at the very least an ambiguous name like Simcha or Yona.