# Is it okay to name child after sefer?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, names

I heard about a recent simcha in our local community where the father named his son Tanya (of which he happens to study).

Is there any sources that support or speak against naming ones child after a sefer?

Comment: Tanya is the 237th most common name in the US accd to Wikipedia. Are you sure he's naming after a book? Maybe the book has a name that could also be a person's name

Comment: @DoubleAA Oh most definitely. I wouldn't have mentioned the sefer if that wasn't important and relevant to the question.  Did your source mention it's the 237th most common name amongst males?

Comment: _USAGE: Tanya, of Latin origin, is a very popular first name. It is more often used as a girl (female) name. People having the name Tanya are in general originating from Azerbaijan, Belarus, Bulgaria, Ireland, Moldova, Netherlands, Russia, Slovakia, Ukraine, United Kingdom, United States of America. MEANING: Fairy queen_ - @DoubleAA I doubt it's relevant to this boy Tanya's name.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/what-type-of-name-should-an-androgynous-be-given#comment104106_38316

Comment: How about asking _are there any rules when naming a child?_ - Why would a Sefer be any different than a flower (Shoshana), animal (Dov), critter (Devora), etc.

Comment: Can you suggest any reason that support or speak against  naming a child after a sefer? (A friend of mine was at a circumcision where R. Ovadiah Yosef served as sandak. When the father gave the name ‘Meor Yisrael’ (the name of a set of books by ROY) ROY smiled but didn’t voice any objection. Lest you argue he wouldn’t nec. have intervened if he didn’t agree with the name - I know with certainty that at times he had objected and instructed/suggested a different name.)